# C# Linq to SQL problem with re-ordering by Code (varchar)

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I am building a Payroll application in C# (learning C#) that will integrate into SAP Business 1. 
When creating tables in SAP, SAP generates two fields automatically in user defined tables. One is Code - (primary key) and another is Name. Both are of type varchar/alphanumeric.

I have this query that returns the results although not in the fashion I want. I.e

```
Code    Name    U_Tax_year  U_Minimum_pay   U_Maximum_pay   
0        0        2011                 1         1  
1        1        2011                 2         2  
10      10        2011                11        11  
11      11        2011                12        12  
2        2        2011                 3         3  
3        3        2011                 4         4  
4        4        2011                 5         5  
5        5        2011                 6         6  
6        6        2011                 7         7  
7        7        2011                 8         8  
8        8        2011                 9         9  
9        9        2011                10        10
```

This is due to the fact that Code and Name are not integer fields.

Below is my query:

```
// Get service instances
            var nhifTableSlabService = Program.Kernel.Get<INHIFTableSlabService>();

//Query database
            var nhiftableSlabs = from tb in nhifTableSlabService.GetAllNHIFTableSlabs()
                                where tb.U_Tax_year.ToString().Trim().Equals(cb_tax_year.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                orderby int.Parse(tb.Code.ToString()) descending
                                select tb;

            if (nhiftableSlabs.Any(x => x != null) 
            {
                // Enable datagridview
                dataGridView1.Visible = true;

                ...bla bla
            }
```

How do I get the results, convert the Codes to integers so that I can finally display the results in descending order of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Convert.ToInt32()` instead of `int.Parse` and you are good to go. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But even when using Convert.ToInt32(), I still have the same problem

Comment: do you get an exception or it just doesn't sort right? did you try to look at the generated sql statement using a profiler?

Comment: It just doesnt sort right. I used intelliTrace on Visual Studio 2010, and the generated sql statement does not have an order by clause. Just a select from table...I must be having some syntax problem

Comment: Try to change the query format to a lambda, you get less chance of screwing things up